# RegEx for capturing scientific citations

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to capture brackets of text that have at least one digit in them (think citations). This is my regex now, and it works fine: https://regex101.com/r/oOHPvO/5

```
\((?=.*\d).+?\)
```

So I wanted it to capture `(Author 2000)` and `(2000)` but not `(Author)`.

I am trying to use python to capture all these brackets, but in python it also captures the text in the brackets even if they don't have digits.

```
import re

with open('text.txt') as f:
    f = f.read()

s = "\((?=.*\d).*?\)"

citations = re.findall(s, f)

citations = list(set(citations))

for c in citations:
    print (c)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to capture on 2000?

Comment: I do, sorry if that was unclear.  (Author 2000) YES, (2000) YES, (Author) NO.

Comment: You can use only (\d+) to capture 2000

Comment: Right, but that wouldn't catch (Author 2000)

Comment: Try preceding your string with r: `r"..."`. This will ensure that no character is treated as an escape character.

Comment: Have you checked the code generated by 101 ?

Comment: Brilliant, didn't realize you could do that!

Comment: I think you need `r'\((?=[^()]*\d)[^()]*\)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that did it, thanks!

Comment: I posted a bit more enhanced version of it, since on second thought, the lookahead looks redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'\([^()\d]*\d[^()]*\)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M5RlSd/1)

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()\d]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(`, `)` and digit
- `\d` - a digit
- `[^()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(`, `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C(%5B%5E()%5Cd%5D*%5Cd%5B%5E()%5D*%5C)):

[image]

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/r4mh5y):

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"\([^()\d]*\d[^()]*\)")
s = "Some (Author) and (Author 2000)"
print(rx.findall(s)) # => ['(Author 2000)']
```

To get the results without parentheses, add a capturing group:

```
rx = re.compile(r"\(([^()\d]*\d[^()]*)\)")
                    ^                ^
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/3ftMsM).

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to possibly handle this expression might be to add boundaries as your expression would likely grow. For example, we could try creating char lists, where we wish to collect our desired data:

```
(?=\().([a-z]+)([\s,;]+?)([0-9]+)(?=\)).
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ZvjOVg/1)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?=\().([a-z]+)([\s,;]+?)([0-9]+)(?=\))."

test_str = "some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author 2000) some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author, 2000) some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author 2000) some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author; 2000)"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /(?=\().([a-z]+)([\s,;]+?)([0-9]+)(?=\))./mgi;
const str = `some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author 2000) some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author, 2000) some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author 2000) some text we wish before (Author) some text we wish after (Author; 2000)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. This produces weird results if there's no number though, like so: https://regex101.com/r/LYkjqH/2